# Create a File From Binary Data In C#

Tags: c#, windows, file, binary, binarystream

I am trying to read a file in binary and create a file of the same format with that binary, this file can be in any commom format like `(.docx, .txt, .jpeg, .png )` etc.

I created a text file `(test.txt)` that has a string `This is a text string` written in it.

```
string file = "filelocation";    //this has a file location 

byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileWithExt);     //  this gives me binary data.....
```

Now how do i create a file of the same extension with the binary data. ?

Comment: Which specific bit are you confused by? Getting the file extension? Adding the file extension to a new filename? Writing binary data to the new file? Something else?

Comment: Writing the data to a new file...

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes`?

Comment: I remain always a bit perplexed by these questions. They are not very common but neither very rare. If you have a method called ReadAllBytes it takes no great immagination to think about the existance of a WriteAllBytes. So the culprit is always the same. [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)

Comment: Is that all you're doing?  Wouldn't copying it be easier?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=net-5.0

Comment: @DanCsharpster I am actually trying to encrypt it and save it with the same format and also with a function to decrypt.

Comment: Oh okay.  You could let .NET encryption encrypt it for you after you've already saved it to disk.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=net-5.0

Comment: Also, following this walkthrough might be helpful.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/walkthrough-creating-a-cryptographic-application

Comment: @DanCsharpster Thanks, that was what I needed.

Comment: Cool!  I would suggest updating your question to reflect that, then, to help others.  I can post this as the answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comment feedback, this is more about encryption than just binary file I/O.

Encryption can be done on a file after it is already saved:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=net-5.0

And for basic guidance on working with encryption and files in C#, I'd suggest this Microsoft example walkthrough:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/walkthrough-creating-a-cryptographic-application

Answer (score 0):

may be this could be helpful

```
// Specifing a file name 
var path = @"file.txt"; 

// Specifing a new file name 
var nPath = @"file2.txt"; 

// Calling the ReadAllBytes() function 
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path); 

// Calling the WriteAllBytes() function 
// to write the file contents with the 
// specified byte array data 
File.WriteAllBytes(nPath, data);
```